"error in PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid."
Хотел поизучать библиотеку PyBluez, но при скачивании выдаёт ошибку, не связанную с pip:
Collecting pybluez
  Using cached PyBluez-0.23.tar.gz (97 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


Какая версия Python?

@Alexey Python 3.11.9

@Alexey а ой может я забыл обновить пайтон...

нет, ошибка все та же, то есть не в пайтоне дело

pip install git+https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez.git#egg=pybluez такую команду пробовали? Может понадобиться "Microsoft C++ Build Tools" для сборки

pip install git+https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez.git#egg=pybluez Collecting pybluez   Cloning https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez.git to c:\users\kozlo\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-gqmtp_n4\pybluez_630545b9e75d4445afec419bad85cbc2   ERROR: Error [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл while executing command git version ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?
@mrgervant

Ну это значит Вам ещё и git нужен для Windows

Вот стоило отредактировать заголовок (вынести в него проблему), так я смог загуглить и найти ответ на enSO. Может это вам поможет?

А тот вопрос закрыт по причине дубликата уже имеющегося другого вопроса
